# I integrated $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x-x^2} dx$ after a $u$-substitution and trig substitution, but I'm not sure what to do with the limits

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I'm a bit lost on the technique in this problem and could use some insight. When do we have to change the  limits?

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x-x^2} dx$$

completing the square gives me:

$$\int \sqrt{-x^2 +x - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} } dx$$

$$\int \sqrt{-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{4}} dx$$

$$ \int \sqrt{-u^2 + \frac{1}{4}} du$$

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - u^2} du$$'

Is trig sub the best way to go?

if $u = \frac{1}{2} \sin \theta$ then $du = \frac{1}{2} \cos \theta d \theta$

$$ = \int \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \sin^2\theta} \frac{1}{2} cos \theta d \theta$$

$$ \int \frac{1}{2} cos \theta \frac{1}{2} cos \theta d \theta$$

$$\frac{1}{4} \int cos^2 \theta d \theta$$

using half angle identity I eventually get:

$$ \frac{1}{4} \int \frac{1}{2} ( 1 + cos(2 \theta)) d \theta$$

$$\frac{1}{8} \int (1 + cos(2 \theta) d \theta$$

$$ \frac{1}{8} ( \theta + \frac{1}{2} sin 2 \theta)$$

Where do I go from here? I'm a bit lost as to what to do with the u sub and how to get back to x from here.

Comment: $u= {1 \over 2} \sin \theta$ means $2u = \sin \theta$, so $\theta = \sin^{-1}(2u)$ and ${1 \over 2} \sin 2\theta = \sin \theta \cos \theta = 2u \sqrt{1-4u^2}$

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057924

Comment: What's the intuition behind changing limits of integration?

Comment: $$B(3/2,3/2)$$?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend changing the limits every time we substitute. Here, that leads to
$$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac14-u^2}\,du$$
($u=x-\frac12$ runs from $0-\frac12$ to $1-\frac12$)
$$\frac14\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta d\theta$$
($u=\frac12\sin\theta$, so since $\sin\theta$ runs from $-1$ to $1$, $\theta$ runs from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$) 
$$\left[\frac18\left(\theta+\frac12\sin(2\theta)\right)\right]_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\theta=\pi/2} = \left(\frac{\pi}{16}+0\right)-\left(-\frac{\pi}{16}+0\right) = \frac{\pi}{8}$$
If you do it that way, there's no need to go back -- we just evaluate the integral right there.

Definite integrals have more tools we can use than indefinite integrals. Even at the basic calculus level you're at, symmetry comes up a lot -- the integral of an odd function from $-a$ to $a$ is zero, for example. If we turn a definite integral problem into an indefinite integral problem and then only convert back at the very end, we lose access to those tools. So then, it makes sense to always bring the limits along and convert them when substituting in an indefinite integral problem.

> Is trig sub the best way to go?

No, the best way to go is to not calculate any antiderivatives at all. Once you reach that first line I wrote down (the same point you were at when writing this line, plus the limits), recognize it as the area of a semicircle of radius $\frac12$. From that, we immediately conclude the result $\frac12\pi\left(\frac12\right)^2=\frac{\pi}{8}$.

That is, of course, not something we could ever have done with an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you are aware, this can be handled with the [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and by extension the [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) Function.

Here you have:

\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{x - x^2}\:dx = \int_0^1 \sqrt{x\left(1  - x\right)}\:dx = \int_0^1 x^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1  - x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\:dx\\& = B\left(\frac{1}{2} + 1, \frac{1}{2} + 1 \right)= B\left(\frac{3}{2} , \frac{3}{2}  \right)
\end{align}

Using the [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function) between the Beta and the Gamma Function this becomes:

\begin{equation}
I = B\left(\frac{3}{2} , \frac{3}{2}  \right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)\cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \right)} = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)^2}{\Gamma\left(3\right)} = \frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \right)^2}{2} = \frac{\pi}{8}
\end{equation}

Comment: @jmerry - Comment Flagged.

Comment: Comments are not designed for discussions. You need to work on your manners.

Comment: Or, in more practical terms, we use this relationship and the value of the integral to calculate $\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)$, as noted in the article linked to for the Gamma function.

Comment: One of the greatest elements of mathematics is the complex yet definitive relationships that exist between elementary and non-elementary functions. It is never invalid nor impractical to consider and speak to every possible relationship. Yes, this is a complex approach to the problem but in learning the relationship the OP may be able to utilise this for similar yet not so elementary definite (or otherwise) integrals. 

Its bizarre I have to say on MSE to a member of 6K rep, but it's never a bad thing to learn alternative methods.

Comment: Oh, alternative methods are great. It's just that in this case, the relevance of the alternative method is a lot higher if we flip the logical arrow around. Elementary exact values of the Gamma function are few and far between - so how do we calculate it for half-integers? Straight from the definition, we could substitute and get the integral of a Gaussian (times an even power of $x$). Or, we could calculate $B(\frac32,\frac32)$ as the elementary integral it is to get $\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)$. $B(\frac12,\frac12)$ for $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)$ also works well.

Comment: @jmerry - If you ever are interested in answering any of the questions I pose, please don't employ this logic. I want any and every possible method to be posted.

Comment: I'm unaware of these functions, but noted.